# Spike in Cadvisor container_network_receive_bytes_total Metric in a Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, promql, cadvisor, metricsql

#### Summary:

I'm using Cadvisor with Prometheus in multiple Kubernetes (k8s) clusters to monitor network traffic usage. I utilize the container_network_receive_bytes_total metric in a query to calculate the total network traffic usage. However, I'm encountering an unusual issue in one of the clusters.

#### Problem:

In one of my clusters, I have a non-production database that has been running smoothly for 20 days. However, starting from yesterday, the container_network_receive_bytes_total metric has shown a significant spike in usage, even though I am certain there is no increase in load. This issue is not isolated. I have encountered similar occurrences multiple times, and they all seem to happen in this particular cluster. I attempted numerous approaches to reproduce it, but I was unable to do so.

This is the query I'm using :

```
(
    sum (
        increase (
            container_network_transmit_bytes_total{namespace="TEST"}[2d]
        )
    ) by (node, cluster, namespace, pod)
) / 1000000000
```

And this is the spike :
[image]

I believe the root cause of this issue lies within this cluster, but I am seeking guidance or clues on how to troubleshoot and resolve it.

Comment: Consider to ask sys-admin questions on https://serverfault.com instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Comment: I won't call it a spike, as it's a sum. I think it should keep growing, no ?

Comment: Yes, it should keep growing, but since there's no increase in load 323G is a really large number. And this pod is just a database so this amount of usage is surely wrong for some reason.

Comment: Check resource utilization in the cluster, including CPU, Memory and network resources. High resource utilization can lead to unusual spikes in metrics. Make sure that the cluster have enough resources to meet workload demands.

Comment: Consider also Node level. Aside for the pod-level metrics, consider also the Node resource utilization same with cluster, check also the CPU, memory and network utilization. If there is an Alerting feature in Prometheus it'll be better to set one to notify when the network traffic spikes. Check other data like packet capture, network flow data or logs to get more detailed information about any unusual behavior.